# Linux kernel: help understanding xfs structs

Tags: c, struct, linux-kernel

I'm currently working on a project involving the exploration of the linux kernel, particularly the XFS filesystem , right now I'm trying to read where a file resides on disk and i stumbled upon the xfs_ifork struct which looks like:

```
typedef struct xfs_ifork {
   int         if_bytes;   /* bytes in if_u1 */
   int         if_real_bytes;  /* bytes allocated in if_u1 */
   struct xfs_btree_block  *if_broot;  /* file's incore btree root */
   short           if_broot_bytes; /* bytes allocated for root */
   unsigned char       if_flags;   /* per-fork flags */
   union {
       xfs_bmbt_rec_host_t *if_extents;/* linear map file exts */
       xfs_ext_irec_t  *if_ext_irec;   /* irec map file exts */
       char        *if_data;   /* inline file data */
   } if_u1;
   union {
       xfs_bmbt_rec_host_t if_inline_ext[XFS_INLINE_EXTS];
                       /* very small file extents */
       char        if_inline_data[XFS_INLINE_DATA];
                       /* very small file data */
       xfs_dev_t   if_rdev;    /* dev number if special */
       uuid_t      if_uuid;    /* mount point value */
   } if_u2;
} xfs_ifork_t;
```

my lead on the u1 union, which encases different scenarios of file data fork, but i cant seem to have figured out the exact way to read them , the xfs_bmbt_rec_host_t struct refers to the disk address , written inside 2 uint64 types which encapsulates the entire address i need,
but somehow, the address I'm able to read isn't the correct one, so goes for the xfs_ext_irec_t struct, which holds the xfs_bmbt_rec_host_t struct and counters.
if someone happens to know theses structs well or have used them i would appreciate some explaining

Comment: I'm guessing the `if_flags` member indicates which union members are valid.

Comment: Yes, they do, i was probably unclear in my question, the if_flags does indicate which member is valid but i'm talking about the valid members of each struct, the data represented by those structs is usually wrong or unavailable.